# How can I make Cargo execute a build script and use a target-specific linker at the same time?

Tags: build, linker, rust, rust-cargo

I'm adjusting the build process of a library written in Rust. The goal is to have it compile on Windows with MSVCC. Due to some specific dependencies, I have to make sure that the correct MSVCC linker is being used, so I've set up a project-specific configuration file for Cargo with:

```
[target.x86_64-pc-windows-msvc]
linker = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/VC/bin/amd64/link.exe"
```

When I run `cargo build` now, my build-script `build.rs` is no longer executed. Since the script provides the paths for important libraries, the building process eventually fails.

To reproduce the problem under Windows 10 (64-bit) with Visual Studio 12, create a project as follows:

```
|   build.rs
|   Cargo.toml
|
+---.cargo
|       config
|
\---src
        main.rs
```

./build.rs:

```
use std::env;

fn main() {
    let manifest_dir = env::var("CARGO_MANIFEST_DIR").unwrap();
    panic!("Building!");
}
```

./Cargo.toml:

```
[package]
name = "some_binary"
version = "0.1.0"
build = "build.rs"
```

.cargo/config:

```
[target.x86_64-pc-windows-msvc]
linker = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/VC/bin/amd64/link.exe"
```

src/main.rs:

```
fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

When you call `cargo build`, linking should fail with

> LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file
>   'advapi32.lib'

Answer (score 2):

#### Update:

Currently, the stable version of Rust fails at including the proper libraries (namely the Windows SDK) when the VS linker is specified explictly. Consequently, the build-script could not be linked and building failed.

#### Solution:

Recent changes in the nightly have solved this problem. Just switch to the nightly or wait until it is merged to the stable version.